# Java: Accessing member of a derived class when an object is declared as a base class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class called ScalarObject and a class called Variable that inherits from ScalarObject. I defined "equals" on ScalarObject that always returns false, and on Variable that returns true when the strings representing them are equal.

The following code:

```
ScalarObject a1 = new Variable("a");
ScalarObject a2 = new Variable("a");
System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));
```

return false. The following code:

```
Variable a1 = new Variable("a");
Variable a2 = new Variable("a");
System.out.println(a1.equals(a2));
```

returns true. The following code:

```
ScalarObject a1 = new Variable("a");
ScalarObject a2 = new Variable("a");
System.out.println(((Variable) a1).equals(((Variable) a2)));
```

also returns true. The problem is that I have other classes that also derive from ScalarObject. I have parts of my program objects that are declared of type ScalarObject but could be a member of any class that derives from it, so casting a ScalarObject object to a derived type won't work. For example, in one part of my program I have:

```
protected void neighbor_simplify(LinkedList<ScalarObject> L, char op) {
 ...
   if(n1 instanceof Variable && n2 instanceof Variable) {
    System.out.println(((Variable) n1).getSymbol());
    System.out.println(((Variable) n2).getSymbol());
   }
   if(n1.equals(n2)) { // x+x=2*x
    System.out.println("B ");
```

and the program prints out "x" twice but does not print "B". The variables n1 and n2 come from the linked list "L". I suspect that the program is calling "ScalarObject.equals()" (which always returns false) and not "Variable.equals()". The problem with casting n1 and n2 to type Variable is that n1 and n2 could be instances of some other class that is also derived from ScalarObject. How do I get the program to call a member from a derived class not a base class even when it is declared as a base class?

I am using NetBeans 6.9.1 on Windows Vista.

Searching on the web has taken me to http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_a_base_class_access_members_of_a_derived_class which states that in Java a base class can access members of a derived class when @Override notation is used. However, when I added @Override to Variable.equals(), I got an error stating that the method does not override a method from a supertype, probably because the siguatures are different. ScalarObject.equals() takes an argument of type ScalarObject and Variable.equals() takes an argument of type Variable.

Comment: Problem is, that the signatures of all equals methods should be the same. I assume you havn't defined them correctly.

Comment: You suspect wrong.  If the class of the object to the left of the `.methodName` is `DerivedClass` then the version of `methodName` in `DerivedClass` will be called (assuming signatures match).  The declared class of the reference variable does not affect this.

Comment: According to Joshua Bloch, one of the major problems with inheritance is "you can't add a value component to an inherited class without breaking the equals contract."  In my opinion, equals(Object o) serves mainly to make an object-oriented programmer's life that much more miserable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be very careful with the difference between *overriding* and *overloading*.

If the signatures of the `equals` methods in the base and the derived class match (which should be the case, see jtahlborn's answer), you have overriding. This uses *dynamic binding*: the correct equals method is determined at runtime, so

```
ScalarObject a1 = new Variable("a");
a1.equals(...);
```

calls the equals of `Variable`, since the type of `a1` is determined as `Variable` at runtime.

---

If the signatures of the `equals` methods don't match (`equals(ScalarObject so)` vs `equals(Variable v)`), you have overloading. This uses *static binding*. That is, even if you do

```
Variable a1 = new Variable("a");
ScalarObject a2 = new Variable("a");
a1.equals(a2);
```

the last line will use `ScalarObject.equals(ScalarObject so)`, because the compiler cannot infer that `a2` is of type `Variable`.

Long story short: always use overriding for your equals method, that is, use `public boolean equals(Object o)`.

Answer (score 4):

the equals method *must* be defined as `public Object equals(Object obj)` in all classes in order for them to override correctly (hint, listen to the `@Override` annotation compilation error).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is make Variable's equals method override ScalarObject.equals by changing it's signature to accept a ScalarObject and then use the instanceof operator to take different actions based on the actual type of the passed in object.